# Trouble adding a delay to camera in iPhone app

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I have in my app, a camera where I would like to add a 3 or 10 second delay for the camera to capture after the specified amount of seconds. I've added a UIPickerView to the cameraOverlayView that shows the number of seconds to delay. So my question is how do I get the camera to take a picture after a 3 or 10 second delay?

Comment: It's not that hard, think this through. How do you execute code after a delay? How do you get the number from the picker? How do you take a picture? Now combine them.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was thinking way to hard on a possible solution but wasn't think of something so simple!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call take picture method of UIImagePickerController after 3.0 or 10.0 seconds using -

```
[self performSelector:@selector(clickPicture:) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];



- (void)clickPicture:(id)sender {
    [camera takePicture];
    // Camera is the object of UIImagePickerController.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general you can get any method to execute after a delay using the NSTimer method...

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

In your case you would want to do something like this...

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delayTimeInSeconds target:self selector:@selector(takePictureMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

If you need more detail than this then you will need to post some sample code.